# MultiViewControl issues

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm presently in the process of reworking a MultiViewControl based wizard process for our web application.  I am having an rough time trying to make sense of the order that events are happening (Page_Load, Init, prerender, etc).  Does anyone out there on the interwebs have details on dealing with one of these controls?  Please don't just say 'google' it.  I've done that and have yet to find a good, comprehensive site yet.

Admittedly, I haven't really elaborated on the problems I'm having with this control, so I'll try to do that:

1. Primary problem is the initialization of UserControls that live in different Views.  In the existing codebase, the programmer was using a combination of multiviewcontrol.ActiveViewIndex = WHATEVER and Response.Redirect("PageWithMultiView.aspx?nextstep")  and it made it all very convoluted.  My task is to attempt to remove the Response.Redirect calls and use only the setting of the ActiveViewIndex.  Is this even possible?  Also,  there are some cases where I need to initialize a control in a particular view only on the initial load and not on subsequent postbacks.  I can use something like the IsPostBack flag but this is only ever set to false on the initial load.  Subsequent reloads IsPostBack == true.  I basically want to have IsPostBack set to false for the initial load of each View.  Can this be done without doing a Response.Redirect to itself?

Hopefully this will make some sense to someone out there.

Thanks.
Greg.

Answer (score 0):

> I am having an rough time trying to
>   make sense of the order that events
>   are happening (Page_Load, Init,
>   prerender, etc).

Here you have all details about ASP.NET page lifecycle and events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx .

In terms of MultiView - you should NEVER use Response.Redirect when you work with MultiView.

If user can not switch to previous view then you can check previous ActiveViewIndex value before setting it to the new value, e.g.

```
if (mv.ActiveViewIndex != newIndex)
{
    // this view is displayed for the first time
}
```

If user can switch to the previous views, I suggest to place an information about already used views in session or by placing hidden field on the form with ids of the views that have already been displayed and to use that information instead of IsPostBack.